# MySql - Pulling two different sums from the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a game with a MySql database. In the game we have a system where characters have a debt that can be paid. We track each debt singularly and flag whether its paid or not with a Boolean 0,1.

I am trying to understand how in a single query I can sum the total paid amount as well as the total owed amount from a single character ID. The tables are
charid, amount, paid (the boolean)

Currently if I just want to find out how much they owe I simply place

```sql
SELECT sum(amount) FROM debts WHERE paid='0';
```

So how would I modify this to create a resulting column for both `paid='0'` and `paid='1'` ?

Thanks all.

Comment: With a small change in requirement from columns to rows you could have `SELECT paid, SUM(amount) FROM debts GROUP BY paid ORDER BY paid`; Watch out for the none paid and all paid cases when fetching the results in the application language.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation. Since the `paid` flag holds `0/1` values, you can just do:

```
select
    sum(paid * amount) amount_paid,
    sum( (1 - paid) * amount) amount_owed
from debts
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `conditional aggregation` using `select case`.

```
SELECT
    sum(case when paid = 0 then amount else 0 end) as not_paid
    ,sum(case when paid > 0 then amount else 0 end) as paid
FROM debts
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user, paid, SUM(amount) total FROM debts GROUP BY user, paid
```